# Host Instance restarted continuosly

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We have a BizTalk Server 2016 with 4 nodes and multiples Host. In one of the servers, there is a Host Instance that continuosly is restarted with this message in the Event Viewer > System:

> The BizTalk Service BizTalk Group :  service
>   terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 5 time(s).  The following
>   corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the
>   service.

In Event Viewer > Application, there isn't any log about an error or something similar.

How can we detect the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend, since you have 3 other Host computers...

1. Repair, then reapply all Service Packs, Feature Packs etc. to the same level as all other computers.
2. Run and see what happens.  If it still fails...
3. a) Delete/Recreate the crashing host.  b)Reinstall/repair all applications that use that host.
4. Run ans see what happens.

Since you do have other hosts, you can take a methodical approach to this.  No rush.

Comment: But it's only one Host Instance, we have 18 and the others runs without problems. Is any location where we can see more information, traces,..?

Comment: No. :(  If it's not in the Event Log, it's nowhere.  You can just skip to step 3a, its' something running *inside* that host that's causing the problem. @felixmondelo